# Is valid CSS “important”? (The jQuery UI CSS doesn’t validate.)

Tags: css, validation, standards, w3c

[Observe](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator?uri=http://jqueryui.com/demos/&profile=css21&usermedium=all&warning=1&lang=en#css) that the jQuery UI CSS does not pass validation.

I try to adhere to standards wherever I can find them.  I'm looking at jQuery UI and wondering why a group of developers that makes a *solid* product doesn't seem to even acknowledge the W3C-imposed standards.

Is the [W3C CSS Validator](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/) just too picky? Or should I pay better attention to these errors/warnings?

Is valid CSS important to adhere to? Why do you feel it's important?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In perfect world, yes it would be important.  In reality, to make CSS look aewsome in every single browser requires some... creativity.  The result is that it may not be strictly valid, but works in (for example) IE and Safari both, even they can interpret the same rules very differently.

I think HTML validation is much more important, because its your content.  Screen readers or other accessibility aids depend on standardized and well structured content.  But CSS is just to make things look nice.  And if it looks nice every you want it be, then I would call that perfectly "valid".

Answer (score 4):

Also try validating in 3.0 instead of 2.1. That takes care of about 20ish errors.

Alot of the errors are errors of unknown properties which are browser specific (such as `-moz-opacity`). Observe how many of the remaining 112 errors include '-moz-', '-webkit-' or something regarding IE filters. These properties are used to achieve consistency across browsers that don't implement the CSS 3.0 spec.

Comment: In the current w3c css validator you can set vendor extensions (like `-moz-` or `-webkit-`) to throw warnings instead of errors. Helps alot.

Answer (score 1):

It is not neccesary to follow standards but I would encourage it to the best of your ability, on that same note it is sometimes necessary to break standards for browser compatibility.

Comment: Or rather, because of browser *incompatiblility*.  Same thing,  I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Validation can be a useful, automated way to spot errors. If you use invalid code intentionally, then you’ve lost your automated way to spot errors.

That said, the validator needs to be upgraded to recognise that `-vendor-` prefixes are valid. (Or the spec needs to be upgraded to classify these prefixes as valid, because they work — c.f. HTML5.)